# US tax liability for a non-resident with a US LLC that does business in the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, limited-liability-company

I'm a non-resident of the US and I've never been to the US. However, I have an LLC in the US. I sell computer software warranty services where we fix computer problems remotely from India. I have a US-based LLC with a US-based business account that gets all my income. I then transfer it to my Indian business account.

Do I pay tax to the US and then also pay it in India for my income, or does my American partner, who holds 15% of the monthly income, pay tax in the US for his income?

We are not selling and physical goods and all transactions take place on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I pay tax to the US and then also pay it in India for my income, or
>   does my American partner, who holds 15% of the monthly income, pay tax
>   in the US for his income?

Of course you do, what kind of question is this? You have income earned in the US by a US entity, and the entity is taxed. Since LLC is a disregarded entity - the tax shifts to you personally.

You should file form 1040NR. You should also talk to a tax professional who's proficient in the Indo-US tax treaty, since it may affect your situation.

Answer (score -1):

It depends and I would not just jump into conclusion as I have seen cases where offering some services are not U.S. sourced income. I'll advise you speak with a knowledgeable tax professional.